# PhpStorm Locate Duplication Option

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm Locate duplication result window showing "2 duplicates, Cost 260' in 3 files".

Can any one tell me What this cost 260 means?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cost of the duplicate is an arbitrary unit calculated using an additive algorithm on the base of the code block size; generally, the larger is the code fragment, the higher is its cost.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/duplicates-tool-window.html